# Append a list from a search function

Tags: python

This is my current code but I am not entirely sure how to append the list with the results of the search. If anyone could provide any help it would be appreciated.

```
import sys
import re

with open('text.log') as f:
    z=[]
    count = 0
    match = re.compile(r'^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(.?)$')
    for l in f:
        if match.search(l):
            z = l.strip().split("\t")[5:8]
            z.pop(1)
            print(z[1]) # Now print them
            print('\n')
            count += 1
            if count == 20:
                print("\n\n\n\n\n-----NEW GROUPING OF 20 RESULTS-----\n\n\n\n\n\n")
                count = 0
        else:
            print('wrong')
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your code has problem! Where are the definitions of x and s? Have a look at it?

Comment: I am not sure could you give me a hint? @fish_ball

Comment: Tell us what x is *supposed* to be - it looks like it's serving two different purposes in your main code vs the tryme() function. Also, where is x defined in tryme()? Should it be a parameter passed in when tryme() is called?

Comment: @ScottLawson I changed the code a little to make it more clear. For some reason it prints every line regardless of the regex so I added the print(ip) sys.exit() line to see what happens. It now prints EVERY line up until one that matches the regex? Why is it printing all the lines instead of just the ones that abide by the regex?

Comment: I have also tried printing only the first entry of the list but it still prints the entirety of the file.

Comment: @user3788715 because your `any(match.search(s) for s in ip)` goes through each line in `ip`, and if that line has an IP address (according to your regex) then you print the WHOLE `ip`, not just the line. Can you explain what your code is trying to do?

Comment: I see. So what modification would I make to print just the line? Yes my code is basically searching through a text file and finding lines that contain an IP address and will print ONLY those lines.

Comment: Maybe a good question, but unclear to understand, and the code cannot even run. Too many gramma mistakes.

Comment: @user3788715 - The most confusing part about your code (for me, anyway) is that you are using the same variable name to build your list *and* to receive the spliced up line. It is currently **z**, but previous edits have had it called **x** and **listofips**. See section 4 of my answer and please tell me if my understanding of your goal was incorrect. BTW, it's especially confusing now because you're question title is about appending to a list, and now your code doesn't even attempt that. Please show us where you want to perform the appending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1) Whenever you have questions about regular expressions, you can use tools like the [Python Regex Tool Site](http://www.pythonregex.com/) to confirm your REs are doing what you think they're doing.

2) In your comment, you said that you don't want every element in **ip** to be printed. The **any()** function will return **True** if *any* of the elements in the iterable are **True**, hence the [function name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any).

```
    if any(match.search(s) for s in ip):
        # this if statement will be true if ANY of the elements of ip match the
        # regex, and all of the statements under it will be executed

        print(ip) # now you're printing the whole list, so even the ones that
                  # didn't match will be printed
```

3) If you want the tryme() function to return just matching elements of the **ip** list, try this:

```
def tryme(ip):
    match = re.compile("^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$")

    return [element for element in ip if match.search(element)]
```

Don't forget to modify the main body of your code to catch the returned list and print it out.

4) You have a useless assignment:

```
with open('text.log') as f:
    listofip=[]
    count = 0
    for l in f:
        listofip = l.strip().split("\t")[5:8] # Grab the elements you want...
```

The second assignment to **listofip** overwrites the the empty list you created, so you should either get rid of the **listofip = []** or use a different name when you splice up your input line. Based on your original question title, I think something like this may be more appropriate for you:

```
import sys
import re
import operator

# using my definition of tryme() from section 3 of my answer

with open('text.log') as f:
    list_of_ips = []
    count = 0
    retriever = operator.itemgetter(5, 7, 8)

    for l in f:
        list_of_ips.append(tryme(retriever(l.strip().split("\t"))))
        count += len(list_of_ips) # add however many ips matched to current count
        if count >= 20:
            print("\n\n\n\n\n-----NEW GROUPING OF RESULTS-----\n\n\n\n\n\n")
            count = 0 # reset count
            list_of_ips = [] # empty the list of ips
```

This will iterate over the file, grab the elements that match your RE, append them to a list, and print them out once there are over 20 in the list. Note that it may print groups larger than 20. I have also added [operator.itemgetter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) to simplify your slicing and popping.

Comment: @user3788715 If you've isolated the problem to a regex issue that has nothing to do with appending to a list, you should search for RE related questions on SO, and ask a new question if you can't figure it out, rather than commenting your question on this thread.